# What is the purpose of javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo.getResourceClass()?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am writing a custom Jersey 2.0 server logging filter.

Sample: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/ServerLoggingFilter.java

A reference to `ResourceInfo` is injected as:

```
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
```

Interface `ResourceInfo` has two methods:

- `Class<?> getResourceClass()`
- `Method getResourceMethod()`

Is there ever a case where `ResourceInfo.getResourceClass() != ResourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getDeclaringClass()`?

Bonus question: Both methods may return `null`.  Is it possible that *only* one would be `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't say much about null values, but there is a case when `getResourceClass() != getResourceMethod().getDeclaringClass()` if you have some class hierarchy like superclass resource. It is easier to show in code, so consider this:

```
public class SuperResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getInfo() {
        return Response.ok("{\"info\":1}").build(); 
    }
}

@Path("test")
public class MyResource  extends SuperResource{
    // ... other endpoints
}
```

Now lets call

```
GET http://localhost:9998/test/

getResourceClass() : class ru.varren.MyResource
getResourceMethod(): javax.ws.rs.core.Response ru.varren.SuperResource.getInfo()
```

Comment: Perfect.  I agree your code sample makes it easier to understand.